# Where is the image/video stored in an NFT?

Tags: solidity, nft

Just get started on Solidity, and it doesn't seem like the image/video is embedded directly into the contract. Where are those assets stored in fact?

Perhaps the approach varies among markets, it would be amazing if you can explain any of them.
Is that the contract store a reference URI to the image/video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right, normally the image/video is not embedded into the contract. That's because saving information to the blockchain is one of the most expensive activities, therefor sending there an image could be very, very expensive. So to avoid this problem, our smart contract contains a link to wherever the media files are stored and all other information. Let's see into this basic NFT contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract BasicNft is ERC721 {
    string public constant TOKEN_URI =
        "ipfs://bafybeig37ioir76s7mg5oobetncojcm3c3hxasyd4rvid4jqhy4gkaheg4/?filename=0-PUG.json";
    uint256 private s_tokenCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("Dogie", "DOG") {
        s_tokenCounter = 0;
    }

    function mintNft() public {
        s_tokenCounter = s_tokenCounter + 1;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, s_tokenCounter);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        // require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");
        return TOKEN_URI;
    }

    function getTokenCounter() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_tokenCounter;
    }
}
```

As you see, TOKEN_URI is equal to string contains a link to a place where information has been saved. When we copy and paste this link to the browser, we found all information which we want to attach to our NFT  (To open this link, if you don't use Brave, you will need IPFS extension in your browser. It's because the information is saved in IPFS (more about it a few lines below)). One of this information is the link to the image.
[image: Here lead link from the contract]

How I said before, we contain image off-chain, because it's a cheaper way. But where exactly could we save our image? For example, in cloud storage like Google Cloud or iCloud. But this option is connected with centralization. The server might go down, you will be unable to access your file, or there could be other options why your link will be broken.

So let's look at the second option. You could store your files in a decentralized alternative to central servers, which still give us possibility to off-chain data storage. By that, I mean IPFS (InterPlanetary File System). IPFS is a distributed file system that seeks to connect all computing devices with the same system of files. It's commonly used free tool. If you send there a file, it won't change and as long as minimum one person will have it pined to his node it will be available. The example use of ipfs you can see in the link used in the smart contract. As you see, it starts by `ipfs://`.

The last way how we can save our file is different from previous. I said we use off-chain methods, but it's not 100% true. There is one method to save image on-chain. The simplicity image we can create by smart contract itself. To this concept, our image should be saved in SVG format.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer here. No, the actual file is not stored on the blockchain. However, information about where the file is stored (usually ipfs) is stored in the NFT Contract and can be retrieved by calling a specific function. That function gives you a URI from where you can see the NFT's metadata including a link to where it is stored.